# Show all Number with exclude number in php

Tags: php, arrays, exception, server, range

How can I display all numbers with the exception of number 3?
I am still learning to use PHP, and it's been around 2 days I can't finish it.

I have made the code listed below, however, I do not know how I can make it not show number 3.

I want to display all content A, B, C, D, E, F, G. except the letter C. in Url like this www.example.com/code.php?id=1 
1 for var id 1 
show all text with except 3 or C

```
<?php
  if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  if(is_numeric($_GET['id']))
  {
    $id = $_GET['id'];

     if($id=='1') 
    {
      while( in_array(($var = range(1,7)), array(3)));
    }
    $id = $_GET['id'];

     if($id=='2') 
    {
      while( in_array(($var = range(1,7)), array(3)));
    }

//---------------------------- Content to show ---------------
if ($var == 1) {
    print 'content A';
}

if ($var == 2) {
    print 'content B';
}

if ($var == 3) {
    print 'content C';
}

if ($var == 4) {
    print 'content D';
}

if ($var == 5) {
    print 'content E';
}

if ($var == 6) {
    print 'content F';
}

if ($var == 7) {
    print 'content G';
}
}
}
?>
```

and show with enter like this

```
content A
content B
content D
content E
content F
content G
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does PHP 'foreach' actually work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work)

Comment: `Warning: implode(): Argument must be an array`

Comment: Add [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see errors on the browser page

Comment: [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: `$a=range(1,7);array_walk($a,function($v){echo$v!=3?$v:'';});`

Comment: What does that code do? According to your output, it does not display any number

Comment: yups, that's what I asked.
I want to display all content A, B, C, D, E, F, G.
except the letter C.
in Url like this
www.example.com/code.php?id=1
1 for var id 1
show all text with except 3 or C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a array_filter ?

```
array_filter(range(1,7), function($item) { return $item !== 3; } );
```

Comment: I use print for content.
so I want to display everything but with an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['id'])){

    $var = range(1,7);

    $arrContent = array(
        'content A', 
        'content B', 
        'content C', 
        'content D', 
        'content E', 
        'content F', 
        'content G'
    );

    $id = (int) $_GET['id']; // Convert id to integer

    if ($_GET['id']) { // If 1
        foreach($var as $key => $value) { // Loop from 1 to 7
            if ($key == 2) { // Skip number 3 which has index 2
                continue; 
            } else{
                echo nl2br($arrContent[$key]."\n"); // Use index in $var to get content with same index
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question.
so it will appear more clearly

Comment: You mean when you run your script it should display all the content at once from A to G except content C?

Comment: Or on enter it should display a random content from A to G except C? Because this what your code is doing actually. You can check the updated answer, don't know if that is what you are looking for, your question still unclear to me.

Comment: please check my post again sir

Comment: Check the updated answer. It will list all content from A to G except C if `id=1`.